# What to check when cronjob is not triggered?

Tags: ubuntu, osx, cron

## Ubuntu

In my Ubuntu VM, I have condigured my cronjob to run a python script every minute just to test

```
#cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*

MAILTO = "myemail@gmail.com"
* * * * * python /home/forge/web-app/database/backup_mysql.py
```

---

It been 5 mins now, I don't see any email send to me.
I don't see any backup file is being generated.

I have a feeling that this cronjob is never got run.

How do I check it ? How do I fix it ?

Do I need to restart some kind of service ?

---

## Steps

I checked `pgrep cron` I got number printing out.

People suggested to remove the spaces between my `=`, I did that as suggested

```
MAILTO="myemail@gmail.com"
```

Restart my cron service

```
sudo service cron restart
```

Yet, same result. It doesn't seem to trigger still.

---

## Max OS

On the other hand, I have this settings in my Mac OS

```
MAILTO = "myemail@gmail.com"
0 * * * *       python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/web-app/database/backup_mysql.py
```

It ran perfecly fine ..

Comment: Why did you add spaces between the `MAILTO`, `=`, and the address?

Comment: @thrig is right. Cron accepts valid shell variables and there shouldn't be spaces around the variable assignment and value.

Comment: Check the `/tmp/cron.log` file to see if it was created with the expected contents or you can check `/var/log/cron` file to see what jobs were run.

Comment: cat: /tmp/cron.log: No such file or directory

Comment: @thrig : omg, seriously, is it that picky ? I'll remove it. Do I need to restart my cron service after editing the cron file.

Comment: I just want to point out 1 thing. I had this line `MAILTO = "sybunlongheng@gmail.com"` on my Mac OS and it work perfecly fine. Email got sent, and scripts got executed !!!

Comment: The space between my `=` is not the issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the log file that you should check is /var/log/cron , to make sure that the cron is running indeed every minute, as scheduled (if not, you should look into a problem with the functionality of the cron daemon).

If the cron daemon is running fine and you task is indeed running every minute, try to run the script manually from CLI (python /home/forge/web-app/database/backup_mysql.py) and see if is returning any output (if your script is not returning an output message, you will not receive any notifications by e-mail).

Finally, based on how the environment is configured, you might want to run the python script, while providing the full path to the python binary:

```
root@bbdfbbeb62b0:~# which python
/usr/bin/python
```